# In a love relationship, is the responsibility of adultery shared or is it individual?

Tags: ethics, social-ethics, virtue-ethics

If a person has sex with another engaged individual, knowing that the individual is engaged/married to another person, is the engaged individual fully moral responsible for the betrayal or is the moral responsibility shared?

What are the school of thoughts on this matter, in the field of moral studies?

Comment: i don't see why this would be different from betrayal in general. they are different sorts of "responsibility". are they both "moral"? not necessarily. i think claiming that they both must be is quite odd. if i do nothing immoral, am i to blame for other people's mistakes? no.

Comment: oh i actually misread that, thought you were asking if it was shared by the other spouse. "thou shalt not covet thy neighbor's wife".

Comment: Responsibility is always individual.

Comment: Both individuals are individually responsible.

Comment: i think a lot of angst in life is driven by the wish that we cannot push people away, only damage (which no-one cares about very much) them. does being overly solitary e.g., a strange or unvirtuous character in general, mean we are morally to blame for the repercussions? arguably so, but these thing blur into mental illness, and anyway, in lieu of immoral actions you are just who you are, whoever that is

Comment: this is worded so weirdly haha. i guess it's uhh code for sex without love

Answer (score 2):

If the knowledge of the engaged individual's marital status is shared with the extra-marital partner either on purpose or not, the moral responsibility falls to both of them. There are multiple points of communication that need to exist to determine whether there is actually any wrongdoing, namely if the extramarital sex is actually considered a betrayal instead of simply an indulgence of acceptable nature.

For the extramarital partner, knowingly engaging in intercourse with the engaged partner without at least second-hand consent from the other person in the engagement would be considered immoral, as there is a potential for conflict should the relationship be found out.

The engaged person needs to communicate the boundaries of the extramarital relationship to the possible extramarital partner, as setup by them and their engaged. In turn, there must be communication between the two engaged people about what said boundaries look like, again due to possible conflict should communication not occur.

However, if the marital status of the engaged is not known to the extramarital partner, then the responsibility of the betrayal (and any possible ramifications) is entirely the fault of the engaged.

Answer (score 0):

Amusing. Obviously, it's a tangled web we weave, but infidelity is an action, and I am not usually in control of other people's, unless I am very suggestive (that's schizophrenic bloom). If I give my other half permission, then yes. If not, then no way am I morally to blame.